# How to define this regular language in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

There is a question in the book "Automata Theory and Applications" that talks about the language

[image: equation describing a language L that consists of all strings w containing only the characters 'a' and 'b' such that there exists a nonempty string x containing only the characters 'a' and 'b' such that w equals the character 'a' followed by the string x followed by the character 'a']

How can I define such a language in Dafny?

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed your question for a week. It looks like it might have been deleted or untagged or something. Anyway, can you please clarify what you're asking? Do you want to know how to define the language L in Dafny? Or to define the theory of regular expressions in Dafny? Or to use regular expressions in practical programs in Dafny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a straightforward transcription of the definition of `L` into Dafny.

```
predicate ContainsOnlyAsAndBs(s: string)
{
  forall c | c in s :: c == 'a' || c == 'b'
}

predicate L(w: string)
  requires ContainsOnlyAsAndBs(w)
{
  exists x | ContainsOnlyAsAndBs(x) && x != [] :: w == ['a'] + x + ['a']
}
```

Note that in Dafny, the type `string` is defined to be `seq<char>`. So we can use the usual built-in methods of manipulating sequences on strings.